# How to get document.referrer in background.html of Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, referrer

I can get tab.url and tab.title but could not find an easy way to get the referrer property for the tab - I dont think there is anything as tab.referrer in Google Chrome Extension.

Answer (score 4):

I've only tested this in popups, but it should also work in a background page. Run this script in your *background.html*:

```
// register your listener
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  var referrer = request.ref;
  // you can now use the referrer
});

// inject script into web site
// this will trigger your registered listener from above
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
  code: "chrome.extension.sendRequest({ref: document.referrer}, function(response) {})"
});
```